# Django IntegrityError (1048, "Column 'item_id_id' cannot be null")

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

```
**The error posted is Integrity Error 1048 column cannot be null**
IntegrityError at /Supply/supplyItems
(1048, "Column 'item_id_id' cannot be null")
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/Supply/supplyItems
Django Version: 4.1.1
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
(1048, "Column 'item_id_id' cannot be null")
Exception Location: C:\Users\63966\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py, line 80, in execute
Raised during:  Supply.views.SupplyItem
Python Executable:  C:\Users\63966\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
Python Version: 3.10.6
Python Path:    
['D:\\CIT\\3rd Year\\IM 2\\New '
 'folder\\sarisaristoreproject\\sarisaristoreproject\\sarisaristoreproject',
 'C:\\Users\\63966\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\63966\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\63966\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\63966\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310',
 'C:\\Users\\63966\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 15 Oct 2022 07:25:53 +0000
```

Here is my models.py

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
    supplier_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    company_address = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    company_num = models.IntegerField(null=False)

    def __str__(self):
       return str(self.company_name)

class supplyItem(models.Model):
    item_id = models.ForeignKey('Items.Items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    supplier_id = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    numOfItemsS = models.IntegerField()
```

Items model from different App:

```
class Items(models.Model):
   item_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   item_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
   item_qty = models.IntegerField(null=False)
   item_prc = models.FloatField(null=False)
   purchase = models.ManyToManyField('registration.Customer', through='Purchase.purchasedItem', related_name='items', blank=True)
   sell = models.ManyToManyField('registration.Employee', through='Sell.sellItem', related_name='items', blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.item_name
```

My views.py

```
class HomeView(View):
    template = 'supply.html'

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template)

class SupplyItem(View):
    template = 'SupplyItems.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = SupplyItemForm()
        return render(request, self.template, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = SupplyItemForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return render(request, self.template, {'form': form})
```

Forms.py

```
class SupplyItemForm(ModelForm):
    itemID = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), queryset=Items.objects.only('item_id'), label='Item name')
    supplierID = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), queryset=Supplier.objects.only('supplier_id'), label='Supplier Company')
    itemQty = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput, label='Quantity')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  # constructor
        super(SupplyItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = supplyItem
        fields = ['itemQty', 'itemID', 'supplierID']

    def clean_itemQty(self):
        qty = self.data.get('itemQty')
        if int(qty) <= 0:
            raise ValidationError('Quantity must be a positive number!')
        else:
            return qty

    def clean_itemID(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data.get('itemID')
        if data == '':
            raise ValidationError('Please select a value!')
        return data

    def clean_supplierID(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data.get('supplierID')
        if data == '':
            raise ValidationError('Please select a value!')
        return data
```

My template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Supply Item</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Supply Store Items</h1>
    <h2>Select Supplier and Items to Supply</h2>
    <hr/>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
         {{form.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" value="Add Store items">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the form when i run the server is this:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you model the field is named `item_id` but in your `ModelForm` the field is named `itemID`. The field names should be the same.

Rename the fields in your `ModelForm` so they match the `Model`.